# Marionette and Backbone. Rendering javascript slider in View

Tags: backbone.js, render, marionette

This is the code:

```
NewEntry_CategoryView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
template: "#NewEntry_Category-template",
tagName: "p",

initialize: function () {
    $("#sliderContainer").slider();
}

});

NewEntry_CategoriesView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
template: "#NewEntry_Categories-template",
tagName: "div",
itemView: NewEntry_CategoryView,
itemViewContainer: '#categoryContainer',

appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
    collectionView.$("#categoryContainer").append(itemView.el);
}
});
```

Why does the jquery ui slider not render when I show the NewEntry_CategoriesView ?

Comment: if I create the slider in an onShow: function(){...} method then I will get a slider but only for the first itemview that is being displayed

Comment: what's `collectionView.$("#categoryContainer")` in your `appendHtml` method? it seems to me you've overwritten this method with no good reason. Can you try removing it and check if it works?

Comment: I figured a solution is to put it in the onShow method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM events/manipulation like `slide()` won't have any effect on the view object's initialization because there is no such DOM element available yet.

Instead, you need to listen to `dom:refresh` of the view to manipulate its DOM element.

So, just put the code in `onDomRefresh`in your ItemView

```
onDomRefresh: function(){ $('#sliderContainer').slide() };
```

This above is a direct fix. But there are two more things to improve:

1. Don't call other div outside of this view when possible. In this case, if `#sliderContainer` belongs to another view, send an event to allow it slide itself. This is not the job of CategoryView. If it is inside current view, refer it with `this.$el.find(".some-div")` or better yet `ui` object.
2. Your collectionView's appendHtml is unnecessary. Marionette also takes of this common case.

Comment: Thank you I did the improvements and now it works. I put it in the onShow method thought. Whats the difference to the onDomRefresh ? Just two different events ?

Comment: And also now I use:  $(self.el).find('#sliderContainer').slider({

Comment: @user3166101, `onDomRefresh` is more reliable than `onShow` for DOM manipulation, where the element is guaranteed in DOM.